# How to Turn console App into Win Form

Tags: c#

How Can I turn this Console Application into a WindowsForm Application?!

```
01  using System;
02  using System.Collections.Generic;
03  using System.Linq;
04  using System.Text;
05  using System.Threading.Tasks;
06  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
07   
08  namespace ConsoleApplication3
09  {
10      class Program
11      {
12          static void Main(string[] args)
13          {
14              string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=vehicles;Uid=root;  Password=toor;";
15              MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
16              MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
17              command.CommandText = "select id, (stock-used) AS total, stock, used FROM `parts`";
18              try
19              {
20                  conn.Open();
21              }
22              catch (Exception ex)
23              {
24                  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
25              }
26              MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
27              while (reader.Read())
28              {
29                  Console.WriteLine(reader["total"].ToString());
30              }
31              Console.ReadLine();
32          }
33      }
34  }
```

Either make it a WPF or a WINDOWSFORM.

I have tried both and I am failing horribly!

Comment: Then post what you have tried with winforms or WPF and what is failing so we can help you.

Comment: You're going to need a User Interface. Have a think about what controls you need to capture and display the required information, then show us what you've got. Not difficult with a bit of thought.

Comment: change `static void main()` to `private void MyFunction()` and change console writelines into something to do with the ui

Comment: what do you mean something to do with the UI? What do I change the Console.Writeline and Console.Readline too?

Comment: Gareth, Im going very basic right now. I am just going to have 1 button in the middle of the WinForm. When you click it, It displays the ToTAL string there from the Database.

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918555/i-need-to-know-what-to-change-to-make-this-console-app-a-winform

Comment: and it was not answered. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Change project Setting...

Application---> OutPut Type --> Window Application(in place of console application)

[image]

Add namespace :

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Add Form1.cs file :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
       }
    }
```

Add this code in Main() :

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: When I change that... nothing happens it does even run. No errors or anything. But I click start and it starts for 2 seconds then stops

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be better off creating a new blank project.

Add a new `Windows Forms Project` to your solution, and create the windows / GUI however you want it to look.

Once that is done, create a new class in that project that will handle the stuff you currently do in your original console application. Copy all the stuff in your current `static void Main(string[] args){ ... }` into some method like this, where you return the data for instance as a list:

```
public List<string> GetData(){
    // ...

    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        data.Add(reader["total"].ToString());
    }

    return data; 
}
```

Now you can use that list of strings with the result in the GUI you created earlier.

---

PS: That SQL query does not look terribly heavy / slow, but if it is, you might want to split the fetching into a separate task or thread at a later time. That would help avoid locking the GUI while you wait for the query to complete.

Comment: could you show me an example with my code

Comment: That _is_ an example with your code; just copy everything in your main method into the `GetData()` method here, and then replace the `Console.WriteLine()` part with a `List` of type `string`, which you can return to your main application. I would recommend you start by experimenting with a blank new Winforms project though, just to see how that works. Hopefully this will make more sense then. :)

Comment: Ohhhh So all the data goes underneath my code, Im sorry I thought you were replacing it

Comment: That`s right, I just left out most of it - just showing the bit you should replace. That will return the stuff you are currently writing out to the console. Now your main application, which should call this method, can iterate over the list, and e.g. show it in a textbox, or whatever else you may want to do with it.

Comment: I did what you told me now I get this error..Error 1 'NewTEST123.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override \\vmdc\users\kevin.miles\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\NewTEST123\NewTEST123\Form1.Designer.cs 14 33 NewTEST123

Comment: That seems to be related to how you've built your application, and beyond the scope of this question. Again, experiment with a Winforms application until you understand how that works first, then call this method from within it later.

Comment: this is what im trying to do. Just as a windows form not a console app.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcD9Jffstmw&list=UUoryLxTF8IQZ36yOTFOrjLQ

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a regular C# console application or open one of your own.
2. Add the following two references to your project and the corresponding “using” statements on top of the main source file:
    *using System.Drawing
    *using System.Windows.Forms
3. Remove the “args” string array parameter from the Main() function.
4. Add “Application.EnableVisualStyles();” as the first call in the Main() function.
5. Change the “Output type” of your project from “Console Application” to “Windows Application.”

   ```
   class Program:System.Windows.Forms.Form  
   {
    static void Main()
      {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.Run(new Program());
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: That would just make it still output to the console, and thus making it look like the application never does anything.